# MSBuild RegexMatch not matching

Tags: regex, msbuild

I have the following

```
<RegexMatch Input="$(Configuration)" Expression="^.*?(?=\.)">
   <Output ItemName="Theme" TaskParameter="Output" />
</RegexMatch>
```

My configuration variable is as follows Theme.Environment

So "Default.Debug" 
or "Yellow.Release"

I would like to get the first portion in to a varaible called theme.
I have tested this regex and it works in stand alone regex testers

```
^.*?(?=\.)
```

but not when used in my build file.

I am echoing the variable out so that i can see the output

```
<Exec Command="echo $(Theme)"/>
<Exec Command="echo $(Configuration)"/>
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that RegexMatch doenst return the matched string but rather returns the entire string if matched.

basically it called IsMatch method not Match method

Have re written as a RegexReplace

```
<RegexReplace Input="$(Configuration)" Expression="\..*" Replacement="" Count="1">
    <Output ItemName="Theme" TaskParameter="Output" />
</RegexReplace>
```

After that it still wasnt working and then i realised i was doing

```
$(Theme)
```

Should have been

```
@(Theme)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you should use MSBuild Community tasks for that - check this line: `<Output PropertyName="Theme" TaskParameter="Output" />`

you should use `PropertyName="Theme"` if you want to refer it like `$(Theme)` later.
`ItemName` will create items set, not property.

But it's much simplier to use MSBuild 4.0 inline functions than Msbuild community tasks for that concrete task. Your code will looks like this (adopt for your script):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTarget="Play">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Yellow.Release</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <Target Name="Play">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <Theme>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(Configuration), `^.*?(?=\.)`))</Theme>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Message Text="$(Theme)" />
    <Message Text="$(Configuration)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Im using vs 2008 so do not have MSBUild 4.0 - hence the need for the community tasks.

Comment: I must have picked up ItemName rather than PropertyName from some example online.  However this does work for other properties im setting.  It just seems to be this one example not working as i expect

Comment: Examples could have some mistakes sometime. Try PropertyName attribute - it should work as expected. Don't forget to accept answer ;).

Comment: sorry, your solution didnt fix my issue.

Comment: It's up to you. Anyway - your answer not error prone - you are using @(Theme) and this is vectorising all items. If your configuration will have more than one dot - you will get all replaced items separated by commas

Comment: That is not true the expression repaces evertyhing after the first dot even if there is more than one dot.  I actually have examples with more than one dot and it works.

Comment: didn't notice you changed expression. I just pointed over @(Theme) syntax.

Comment: had to change the expression as the original expression was to match the first portion, and now that im doing a replace, it hadt to match what was going to be replaced, ie everything after the first portion.